# How do I group by month and year with data count

Tags: mysql

I have a table with data like this:

```
id | question | pub_date
1  | qeustion1| 2012-12-03
2  | qeustion2| 2012-12-06 
3  | qeustion3| 2012-11-03 
4  | qeustion4| 2011-12-03
```

And i want an output like:
It should count the record on the basis of Year, month result count with Desc order and should also display each row data.

In my case:

- Year: 2012 has 3 records
- Month: 12 in year 2012 has 2 records
- Year: 2011 has 1 record
- Month:12 in 2011 has 1 record.

I have tried this:

```
SELECT
    EXTRACT(MONTH FROM pub_date) as month, 
    EXTRACT(YEAR FROM pub_date) as year, 
    Count(id)
FROM 
    mytable
GROUP BY 
    month,
    year
ORDER BY 
    year DESC, 
    month DESC
```

I need to show data like this see **Blog Archive** section of [Site](http://darnnews.blogspot.com/)

Comment: basically things like that you need to do in two querys (one for year and one for month) in your code PHP or other. Maybe you can show Output what you want from your example data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume the result you want is something like:

```
2012           3
2012 12        2
2012 11        1
2011           1
2011 11        1
```

You can get this by using `union` on two aggregation queries:

```
select s.*
from ((select year(pub_date) as yr, NULL as month, count(*) as cnt
       from t
       group by year(pub_date)
      ) union all
      (select year(pub_date) as yr, month(pub_date) as mon, count(*) as cnt
       from t
       group by year(pub_date), month(pub_date)
      )
     ) s
order by yr desc,
         (case when mon is null then -1 else mon end)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
select count(id)
from mytable
group by year(pub_date), month(pub_date)
order by year(pub_date) desc, month(pub_date) desc
```

And if you want to know which months and years are there, use:

```
select year(pub_date) as year, month(pub_date) as month, count(id), *
from mytable
group by year(pub_date), month(pub_date)
order by year(pub_date) desc, month(pub_date) desc
```

Getting the data from the months and also the years

```
select year(pub_date) as year, year_count, month(pub_date) as month, count(rowid) as month_count
from mytable u
, (
select year(pub_date) as year, count(rowid) year_count
from mytable
group by year(pub_date)
) as tab
where tab.year = year(u.pub_date)
group by year(pub_date), month(pub_date)
```

Comment: This will return count only not the data.

Comment: It behaves exactly the same as my query does. I need data as well. did you see the link i mentioned?

Comment: what do you mean by data? I updated the second query, check if that's what you need

Comment: I mean if i have 2 rows with same year, it will show count 2 in one row, not both the rows.

Comment: I think I get it. It is a much more complex query that you need, right?